# afterlabeledit treeview handler c#

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, label

i need to based in what the user wrote in the edition of a node label, rewrite that label with other text. Example if the user wrote "NewNodeName" I want that the node text after finish the edition be "S :NewNodeName".
I try this two codes and i don't know why neither work

```
  private void treeView1_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, NodeLabelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Node.Text = "S :"+ e.Label;
    }
```

and also:

```
        private void treeView1_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, NodeLabelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        treeView1.SelectedNode.Text = "S :"+ e.Label;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, doesn't work, the Text property gets the label value *after* this event runs.  Which is why e.Cancel works.  So the Text value you assigned will be overwritten again by code that runs after raising this event.  Code inside of the native Windows control.

There is no AfterAfterLabelEdit event and you cannot alter e.Label in the event handler, you need a trick.  Change the Text property *after* the event stopped running.  Elegantly done by using Control.BeginInvoke().  Like this:

```
    private void treeView1_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, NodeLabelEditEventArgs e) {
        this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { e.Node.Text = "S: " + e.Node.Text; });
    }
```

Comment: hi Hans, it works flawless. It is like a third in a row of good answers that you gave me, thank you very much.

Comment: xD...the questions i think were good, at least not trivial. And your answers were precise. For example in this question, the use of delegate invocation never cross my mind when looking how accomplish what i need. Now i have one more solution to my repertoire and I'm confident that others users will find useful your answer, VoteUp for that

Comment: This worked for me in my case as well where instead of relabeling the nodes themselves I wanted to replace them with a new node with the new label (I know it is weird, but I have my reasons). Anyways, the CancelEdit trick below which I came up with on my own did not work entirely - the node would be replaced but would stay in the "editing" mode (even with lots of calls to EndEdit). Thanks!

Comment: Could somebody explain exactly why this solution works?  Does the delegate get executed after the event ends?  I'm a bit fuzzy on order of execution.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite late to answer this question, but here's another solution:

1) Remove the part that you want user not to edit of the node label right before you call BeginEdit()

2) In AfterLabelEdit(), set the node text as you want and set NodeLabelEditEventArgs.CancelEdit = true so that the text user input won't replace the text you set

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseDoubleClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Node == null) return;
    e.Node.Text = e.Node.Text.Substring(3, e.Node.Text.Length - 3);
    e.Node.BeginEdit();
}
private void treeView1_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, NodeLabelEditEventArgs e)
{
    e.Node.Text = "S :" + e.Label;
    e.CancelEdit = true;
}
```